# android: how can i create a TextView combining icom?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-drawable, ratingbar

is there an easy way to create a text view with an icon inside the text?
like in this number of rates example:

(** 3,45642)

(I have less then reputeshion 10 so I cant insert the image I wanted

** means an icon of a small man)

or is it part of RatingBar that i couldn't find?

I don't want to use android:drawableLeft="@drawable/my_icon" 
as i feel like the parenthesis are critical.

Many thanks for any help!

Comment: Consider uploading your image elsewhere and linking to it from your question.

Comment: I don't know of a built-in way to achieve this with a single view, but you can construct your own layout with a `TextView` on the left for a parenthesis followed by an `ImageView` and another `TextView` after it.  You will just want to limit your `ImageView` height based on the text height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out SpannableStringBuilder class.

Usage examples are posted here:

http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=android.text.SpannableStringBuilder